# Kamada & Kawai graph layout algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, layout, graph

Anyone out there ever attempted Kamada & Kawai's '88 Algorithm for drawing general undirected graphs?

If so, and you know of any resources on it (apart from the paper itself), links would be appreciated (extra points if anyone knows of any concise, step by step breakdowns).

Thanks!

Comment: I googled "Kamada & Kawai" and the wiki page for "Force-based algorithms (graph drawing)" popped up detailing the algorithm in pseudocode. Do you need citeable sources?

Comment: @das_weezul - Citeable sources would be great, I've found a few but I can't access the papers without paying ridiculous charges :(

Comment: @MichaelHillman If you want more layout algorithms (or a graph framework), you can check out JUNG: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/package-summary.html. I've found that Fruchterman-Reingold creates more aesthetically pleasing layouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you **[search on Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=An%20Algorithm%20for%20Drawing%20General%20Undirected%20Graphs&btnG=&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5)** for the name of Kamada and Kawai's paper "An Algorithm for Drawing General Undirected Graphs", the first hit includes a link, which is broken. But if you click on [**Versions**](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=3559379059294964525&hl=de&as_sdt=0), you can select other sources of the paper as PDF. Here is one for example from the [Wellesley College](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs315/Papers/Kamada-Graph%20Drawing.pdf)

Here is my workflow for getting papers:

1. Search on Google Scholar for `<paper title>`
2. Check all versions
3. Check the university homepage of the author(s)
4. Search for `"<paper title> pdf"` on google search
5. Search the eBook section of my university library

Comment: Knowing the <paper title> is the hard part. I have seen the algorithm mentioned many times but never the name of the paper until this post. This post was only google search or google scholar search which turned up useful results for "kamada_kawai_layout".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late to the party. [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) does implement this algorithm. It is available under layout -->  Edge-weighted spring embedded. for more details, check the
[code source of the algorithm implementation](http://code.cytoscape.org/redmine/projects/cy3-impl/repository/revisions/ae36b88b1a5a8b06dd438dc17babcf3d6fe0bfdc/entry/layout-cytoscape-impl/src/main/java/csapps/layout/algorithms/bioLayout/BioLayoutKKAlgorithmTask.java)

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://graphsharp.codeplex.com which provides a number of layout algorithms for C#.

Answer (score 1):

Kamada-Kawai is implemented in igraph (e.g. the R package, though you can also use it as a Python library I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Even later to the party, but FTR the C++ boost library has an implementation as well:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.html